# falha ao deixar uma url com php get amigavel

Tags: php, htaccess, url, php-7, url-amigavel

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Estou tentando deixar uma URL de uma página que recebe um GET mais amigável.
Porém da erro 500 sempre que acesso ela.
Minha URL: https://minhalojapontocom/loja/detalhes.php?idproduto=22
Como eu quero ela: https://minhalojapontocom/loja/delalhes/22
Mudei pelo .htaccess, com o seguinte código:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^detalhes\/?([0-9]+)\/?(.+)\/?$ detalhes.php?Idproduto=$1
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3):

A sua última RewriteRule não possui o ínicio da URL (/loja/)

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^loja/detalhes\/?([0-9]+)\/?(.+)\/?$ loja/detalhes.php?Idproduto=$1
```

Caso você queira de forma mais genérica, você pode tentar o seguinte: `RewriteRule ^(.*)detalhes\/?([0-9]+)\/?(.+)\/?$ $1detalhes.php?Idproduto=$2` porém tome cuidado que dessa forma irá pegar todas as URL terminadas com "detalhes.php"

Aproveitando, recomendo o site https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ para testar regras de .htaccess